# Why does my Python code with websockets drops

Tags: python, websocket, psycopg2

I have some python code. I connect to the OKX API and trying to get info about my wallet, but after about 24 hours my code stops working and I get some errors. In my code I use `psycopg2==2.9.7` to record coming info, also I use `websocket-client==1.6.4`.

As you can see when my websocket connection is closing I'm trying to reconnect, this is because of after some time my code stop working with no error.

Also I have a problem with recording type of error in function `on_error`. The problem is:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'WebSocketConnectionClosedException'

after that I get:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ProgrammingError'

and then:

> psycopg2.pool.PoolError: connection pool exhausted

So here is my code:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

import websocket
from websocket import WebSocketConnectionClosedException

from config import APIs  # In config.py I keep my API keys secret
from database import DB  # In database.py I have some functions to manipulate with PostgreSQL

api_public = APIs['OKX']['public']
api_private = APIs['OKX']['private']
api_passphrase = APIs['OKX']['passphrase']


db = DB()


def on_open(ws):
    timestamp = str(datetime.now().timestamp())

    request = {
        'op': 'login',
        'args': [{
            'apiKey': api_public,
            'passphrase': api_passphrase,
            'timestamp': timestamp,
            'sign': make_signature(timestamp).decode('utf-8')
        }]
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(request))

    time.sleep(0.1)

    ws.send(json.dumps({
        'op': 'subscribe',
        'args': [{
            'channel': 'account',
            "extraParams": "{\"updateInterval\": \"0\"}"
        }]
    }))


def on_message(ws, message):
    data = json.loads(message)

    if 'event' in data.keys() and data['event'] == 'subscribe':
        date = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
        text = f''' Successfully connected to OKX Wallet WebSocket 

Date: {date}'''
        db.execute('''
            insert into messages(text) values(%s)
        ''', (text,))

        print(text)

    elif 'data' in data.keys():
        for coin in data['data'][0]['details']:
            db.execute('''
                delete from OKXWallet where coin = %s
            ''', (coin['ccy'],))
            db.execute('''
                insert into OKXWallet(coin, amount, date) values(%s, %s, %s)
            ''', (coin['ccy'], coin['availBal'], datetime.now()))


def on_error(ws, error):
    date = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
    text = f''' OKX Wallet 

Error: {type(error)}
Date: {date}'''

    db.execute('''
        insert into exceptions(error, type, comment, date) values(%s, %s, %s, %s)
    ''', (error, str(type(error)), 'OKX Wallet', date))
    db.execute('''
        insert into messages(text) values(%s)
    ''', (text,))

    print(text)

    if type(error) is WebSocketConnectionClosedException:
        main()


def make_signature(timestamp):
    string = timestamp + 'GET' + '/users/self/verify'
    signature = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_private.encode('utf-8'), string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
    return signature


def on_ping(ws, *data):
    pass


def on_pong(ws, *data):
    pass


def on_close(ws, status_code, message):
    print('Close status code -', status_code)
    print('Close message -', message)

    main()


def main():
    url = 'wss://ws.okx.com:8443/ws/v5/private'
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
        url=url,
        on_open=on_open,
        on_message=on_message,
        on_error=on_error,
        on_ping=on_ping,
        on_pong=on_pong,
        on_close=on_close
    )
    ws.run_forever(
        ping_interval=10,
        ping_timeout=9
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is code in database.py

```
from psycopg2.pool import SimpleConnectionPool as Pool


class DB:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = Pool(
            host='localhost',
            port=5432,
            database='postgres',
            user='postgres',
            password='password',
            minconn=5,
            maxconn=15
        )

    def execute(self, query, *args):
        connection = self.pool.getconn()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, *args)
        connection.commit()
        self.pool.putconn(connection)

    def fetchone(self, query, *args):
        connection = self.pool.getconn()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, *args)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        self.pool.putconn(connection)
        return result

    def fetchall(self, query, *args):
        connection = self.pool.getconn()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query, *args)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        self.pool.putconn(connection)
        return result

    def create_tables(self):
        connection = self.pool.getconn()
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        # Creating sequences
        cursor.execute('''
            create sequence if not exists messages_id_sequence increment 1 start 1
        ''')  # messages_id_sequence
        cursor.execute('''
            create sequence if not exists exceptions_id_sequence increment 1 start 1
        ''')  # exceptions_id_sequence
        cursor.execute('''
            create sequence if not exists OKXWallet_id_sequence increment 1 start 1
        ''')  # OKXWallet_id_sequence

        # Creating tables
        cursor.execute('''create table if not exists messages(
            id integer default nextval('messages_id_sequence') primary key,
            text text
        )''')  # messages
        cursor.execute('''create table if not exists exceptions(
            id integer default nextval('exceptions_id_sequence') primary key,
            error text,
            "type" text,
            comment text,
            date text
        )''')  # exceptions
        cursor.execute('''create table if not exists OKXWallet(
            id integer default nextval('OKXWallet_id_sequence') primary key,
            coin text,
            amount double precision,
            date timestamp without time zone
        )''')  # OKXWallet

        connection.commit()
        self.pool.putconn(connection)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DB()
    db.create_tables()
```

I really don't know why I'm getting disconnected after some time.

Here is an error

```
Close message - None
Close status code - None
Close message - None
Close status code - None
Close message - None
Close status code - None
Close message - None
Close status code - None
Close message - None
Close status code - None
Close message - None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 434, in setSock
    dispatcher.read(self.sock.sock, read, check)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 99, in read
    if not read_callback():
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 448, in read
    raise e
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 443, in read
    op_code, frame = self.sock.recv_data_frame(True)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 408, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 447, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 340, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 296, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 375, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 531, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 124, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 553, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'WebSocketConnectionClosedException'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 507, in run_forever
    setSock()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 436, in setSock
    handleDisconnect(e, reconnecting)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 487, in handleDisconnect
    self._callback(self.on_error, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 558, in _callback
    self.on_error(self, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ProgrammingError'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 434, in setSock
    dispatcher.read(self.sock.sock, read, check)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 101, in read
    check_callback()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 480, in check
    raise WebSocketTimeoutException("ping/pong timed out")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketTimeoutException: ping/pong timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 553, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'WebSocketTimeoutException'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 507, in run_forever
    setSock()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 436, in setSock
    handleDisconnect(e, reconnecting)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 487, in handleDisconnect
    self._callback(self.on_error, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 558, in _callback
    self.on_error(self, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ProgrammingError'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 434, in setSock
    dispatcher.read(self.sock.sock, read, check)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 99, in read
    if not read_callback():
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 448, in read
    raise e
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 443, in read
    op_code, frame = self.sock.recv_data_frame(True)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 408, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 447, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 340, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 296, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 375, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 531, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 124, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 553, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'WebSocketConnectionClosedException'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 507, in run_forever
    setSock()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 436, in setSock
    handleDisconnect(e, reconnecting)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 487, in handleDisconnect
    self._callback(self.on_error, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 558, in _callback
    self.on_error(self, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ProgrammingError'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 434, in setSock
    dispatcher.read(self.sock.sock, read, check)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 99, in read
    if not read_callback():
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 448, in read
    raise e
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 443, in read
    op_code, frame = self.sock.recv_data_frame(True)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 408, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 447, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 340, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 296, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 375, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 531, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 124, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 553, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'WebSocketConnectionClosedException'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 507, in run_forever
    setSock()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 436, in setSock
    handleDisconnect(e, reconnecting)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 487, in handleDisconnect
    self._callback(self.on_error, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 558, in _callback
    self.on_error(self, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ProgrammingError'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 434, in setSock
    dispatcher.read(self.sock.sock, read, check)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 99, in read
    if not read_callback():
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 448, in read
    raise e
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 443, in read
    op_code, frame = self.sock.recv_data_frame(True)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 408, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 447, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 340, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 296, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 375, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 531, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 124, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 553, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'WebSocketConnectionClosedException'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 507, in run_forever
    setSock()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 436, in setSock
    handleDisconnect(e, reconnecting)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 487, in handleDisconnect
    self._callback(self.on_error, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 558, in _callback
    self.on_error(self, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ProgrammingError'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 434, in setSock
    dispatcher.read(self.sock.sock, read, check)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 99, in read
    if not read_callback():
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 448, in read
    raise e
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 443, in read
    op_code, frame = self.sock.recv_data_frame(True)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 408, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 447, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 340, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 296, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_abnf.py", line 375, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_core.py", line 531, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_socket.py", line 124, in recv
    raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException(
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection to remote host was lost.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 553, in _callback
    callback(self, *args)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'WebSocketConnectionClosedException'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 507, in run_forever
    setSock()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 436, in setSock
    handleDisconnect(e, reconnecting)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 487, in handleDisconnect
    self._callback(self.on_error, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 558, in _callback
    self.on_error(self, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 20, in execute
    cursor.execute(query, *args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'ProgrammingError'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 138, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 131, in main
    ws.run_forever(
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 514, in run_forever
    teardown()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 401, in teardown
    self._callback(self.on_close, close_status_code, close_reason)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\websocket\_app.py", line 558, in _callback
    self.on_error(self, e)
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\OKX.py", line 85, in on_error
    db.execute('''
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\database.py", line 18, in execute
    connection = self.pool.getconn()
  File "F:\Bots\OKX TEST\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\pool.py", line 92, in _getconn
    raise PoolError("connection pool exhausted")
psycopg2.pool.PoolError: connection pool exhausted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: In your SQL query `db.execute('''insert into exceptions(error, ...)''', (error, ...))` what do you expect the database driver to convert your error into? Plus that websocket package you are using keeps calling your error handler even after the error handler itself fails xD. Here's a few other points you should consider as well: 1) Configure ping-pong for your websocket to less than 30 second as described [here](https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#overview-websocket-connect) 2) Stop using recursion through your callbacks for running the ws forever, use a while loop in your `main` function.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Why should I use `while` in `main` function

Comment: Recursion adds to the stack for each function call. Meaning over time as the websocket connection keeps dropping your program will take up more and more memory. You actually really just want an infinite loop so use a `while True:` loop to do that.

Comment: Rather looking at the documentation of the package you are using why don't you simply specify the `reconnect` parameter of `ws.run_forever`? Your package will then automatically handle those disconnects for you...